# Как решить проблему с многопоточными обращениями к бд sqlite?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

Есть один файл базы данных, в котором несколько таблиц (4-5). Обращение к ней происходит редко (примерно 1 в минуту и бесконечный цикл, который обращается к ней каждые 5 секунд).

Так-то всё работает нормально, но иногда выходит ошибка `sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked` (а с масштабированием данных боюсь будет вылезать ещё чаще)

Как можно реализовать решение данной проблемы? (что-то вроде ожидания, пока бд освободится)

Как вариант пока: создать несколько файлов базы данных, для небольшого распределения нагрузки (но это не особо поможет тк все таблицы между собой  связаны).

Скрипт находится на vps сервере с 512 мб озу, 10 гб ссд (100мб/с) и 1 ядро 2.4ггц  (может перейти на какой-то другой тип субд ака postgresql ?)

Comment: Обращение из одного процесса или из нескольких? Если из одного, можно просто питоновый Lock повесить. Если из нескольких, то почему из нескольких-то?

Comment: Так-то это cgi скрипт, к которому происходит обращение каждую минуту. Ну и бесконечный цикл в коде, который обращается к бд каждые 5 секунд. Скорость ответа этого скрипта не очень важна (могут подождать 1-2 секунды)

Comment: А почему cgi, а не wsgi?

Comment: Да это не важно. Нужно решить проблему с запросами к бд :) Создание для каждой таблицы своего файла должно частично решить проблему, но хотелось бы именно как-то настроить ожидание для других запросов

Comment: Важно то, что sqlite не предаазначен для использования из нескольких процессов, и если вы не хотите использовать wsgi, то и sqlite лучше поменять на что-то другое

Comment: А если перехватить ошибку ? и продолжить ? или заснуть и продолжить?

Comment: Как перехватывать и продолжать предлагаете?) Конечно была идея создать переменную, которая хранила бы состояние базы данных (открыта или нет) и бесконечным циклом ждать освобождение, но это немного некрасиво и жду другие идеи :)